# How to close a frame in Java without closing the cmd prompt?

Tags: java, user-interface, window, windowlistener

Here is the frame (i.e. `java.awt.Frame`) code. When I click the close button on the window it doesn't close and every time I have to close the the cmd prompt from where I launch this program. How to make it close?

```
import java.awt.*;

public class FrameExample {

private Frame f;

public FrameExample () {
    f=new Frame("Hi its Harish");
}

public void launchFrame() {
    f.setSize(470,470);
    f.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    FrameExample guiWindow=new FrameExample();
    guiWindow.launchFrame();
}
}
```

Comment: Why are you not using Swing(ie JFrame)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this listener into your code

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
      System.exit(0);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

implement window listener....

inside `windowClosed` call `System.exit(0)`

Answer (score 1):

AWT frame doesn't support `setDefaultCloseOperation()`. Use,

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        f.dispose();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were using JFrame (swing) rather than Frame (awt), you would use [JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(int)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation%28int%29) and specify EXIT_ON_CLOSE.

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

Since you are not, the WindowListener is the way to go.

Comment: evolve yourself! or write it in assembler!

Answer (score 0):

```
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

It's explained here:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html

Comment: evolve yourself! or write it in assembler!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the close operation:

```
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```